# Could stackoverflow.com/careers redirect to careers.stackoverflow.com?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

I just tried to go to `stackoverflow.com/careers` and got a 404.

Maybe it could redirect to `careers.stackoverflow.com`?

Comment: Seems like something that should have already been done. I'm wondering why stackoverflowcareers.com doesn't do the same thing. Sadly, it appears to be already owned, which is slightly concerning.

Comment: stackoverflowcareers.com is being transferred to our SRE team at this very moment so it'll point at something sensible very soon!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

[image]

Coming to you live in the next prod build.

Comment: What about http://meta.stackoverflow.com/careers? ;)